# Array of parameters in Restangular

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, restangular

I'm trying to pass some filters to my getList method of Restangular.

In my app I have this:

```
var filters = Filters.get();

var query = {};
for (var i in filters) {
  query['filters['+i+']'] = filters[i];
}
query['userId'] = userId;

Restangular.all('pets').getList(query).then(...
```

And in the server side (Node + ExpressJS) I have this:

```
var filters = req.query.filters;
for(var i in filters){
  console.log(filters[i]);
}
```

that is consoling objects like this:

```
{"category":"Tipo","options":[{"name":"Perros","realName":"perro","checked":true},{"name":"Gatos","realName":"gato","checked":true}]}
```

But, I don't know why when I try `console.log(filters[i].category);` is not consoling `Tipo`

Can anyone see something that I am not seeing, or has a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it was a silly mistake! I have to parse the response like this: `JSON.parse(filters[i]);`